# regex to split on pipe character except when in square brackets

Tags: regex, python-re

As the title suggest, I would like to split values on the `|` character except when the `|` character is nested in brackets `[|]`.

For example, taking the text of:

```
H3609|E1.7|E1.3|D09[7|9]
```

where I would like to split out ["H3609", "E1.7", "E1.3", "D09[7|9]"]

So far I have tried something very basic like: `[A-z0-9\.]*` would get back (assuming python using re.`findall()`)

```
["H3609", "E1.7", "E1.3", "D09[7", "9]"]
```

any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```py
re.findall(r'(?:\[[^][]*]|[^][|])+', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yzQQQ2/1).

*Details*:

- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group that groups two patterns:

  - `\[[^][]*]` - a `[`, then any zero or more chars other than `[` and `]` and then a `]` char
  - `|` - or
  - `[^][|]` - any char but `]`, `[` and `|`
- `)+` - repeat matching the group patterns one or more times.

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/tIR3qb):

```py
import re
text = 'H3609|E1.7|E1.3|D09[7|9]'
print( re.findall(r'(?:\[[^][]*]|[^][|])+', text) )
# => ['H3609', 'E1.7', 'E1.3', 'D09[7|9]']
```